# Application_Start not firing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC (beta) application that I'm working on, and am having trouble figuring out if I'm doing something wrong, or if my `Application_Start` method in Global.asax.cs is in fact not firing when I try to debug the application.

I put a breakpoint on a line in my `Application_Start` method, and am expecting that when I attempt to debug the application that the breakpoint should get hit... but it never does. Not after I reset IIS, not after I reboot, not ever. Am I missing something? Why is this method never getting called?

Comment: Does your global.asax page inherit from the global class that your method is in?

Comment: I've bounced into case where the `global.asax` file was simply missing. so that's also worth checking :-)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If this is in IIS, the app can get started before the debugger has attached. If so, I am not sure if you can thread sleep long enough to get attached.

In Visual Studio, you can attach the debugger to a process. You do this by clicking Debug >> Attach to process. Attach to the browser and then hit your application. To be safe, then restart IIS and hit the site. I am not 100% convinced this will solve the problem, but it will do much better than firing off a thread sleep in App_Start.

Another option is temporarily host in the built in web server until you finish debugging application start.

Comment: to expand - (in VS2010, using MVC 3 project type) right click web project > properties > web (tab) and make sure "Use Visual Studio Development Server" is selected radio button. Then your Application_Start breakpoints should be hit just fine.

Comment: Ahhhhhh mannnnnnn, I lost a couple of hours. Again!! Thanks for this answer. :)

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in Visual Studio in the Global.asax.cs under the Application_Start() and it doesn't fire, check your build type. If you are running as a release, this breakpoint may not fire. Switch to Debug and it should stop.

Answer (score 190):

Note : a nice **easy alternative to using the inbuilt "Visual Studio Development Server"** or **IIS Express** (e.g. because you are **developing against IIS and have particular settings** you need for proper functioning of your app) is to simply stay running run in IIS (I use the Custom Web Server + hosts file entry + IIS binding to same domain)

1. wait for debugging session to fire up ok
2. then just make a whitespace edit to the root web.config and save the
   file
3. refresh your page (Ctrl + F5)

Your breakpoint should be hit nicely, and you can continue to debug in your **natural IIS habitat**. Great !

Comment: This is brilliant AppDomain recycle hookup.  Thanks !!

Comment: There is no more Visual Studio Development Server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676527/vs-express-2013-for-web-how-to-use-the-internal-vs-server-not-iis-express

Comment: @mac10688 true, but there is still "IIS Express" which is still generally not the production environment. Updated the answer accordingly thanks.

Comment: Definite accepted answer. I point devices to my IIS that won't allow communicate when using the IIS Express edition! This worked a charm.

Comment: I'd also point out that (past prototyping stages) we should all be trying to develop and debug in the closest possible environment to the intended deployment env. So I'd recommend taking the time to debug in proper IIS (if that's the target for deployment) not any of the stripped down versions. A stitch in time...

Answer (score 65):

The following helps in any case (no matter if you're using IIS, Cassini or whatever):

1. Set your breakpoint in Application_Start
2. Start debugging (breakpoint most probably is not hit) -> a page is shown in the browser
3. Change web.config (e.g. enter a blank line) and save it
4. Reload the page in the browser -> breakpoint is hit!

Why does this work? When web.config is changed, the web server (IIS, Cassini, etc.) does a recycle, but in this case (for whatever reason), the process keeps the same, so you keep attached to it with the debugger (Visual Studio).

Comment: Clone, two years later of http://stackoverflow.com/a/7655582/11635 - consider deleting and putting any extra info in a comment

Comment: actually @RubenBartelink, i think this answer is clearer than the other one, because of the wording and extra explanations.

Comment: @HeribertoLugo I'm cool with that - 50 upvotes is hard to disagree with entirely (Nonetheless, I'd be delighted for edits to the other answer to close the gap if anyone has the time and context; it's been some time since I've used a debugger on IIS!)

Comment: i agree editing the other and removing this one would be the better route.. i saw the other one first and followed it slightly off, so it didnt work.. when i saw this one after spending half hour more on it, then it made more sense.. thats half hour i didnt need to lose..

Answer (score 23):

I'm too having problems with breakpoints in application_start with IIS a hosted app. A good workaround is using Debugger.Break(); in code instead of the VS breakpoint

Comment: I belive that not hitting the breakpoint as something to do with running your app pool in integrated pipeline mode. Are you using that?

Answer (score 11):

I have just the same problem. I have made a lot of renaming in my solution. After it I got two not working web-applications and several another web-applications were all right. I got error that I have wrong routes. When I have tried to setup break point in `Application_Start` method, and then restart IIS, VS didn't break execution. With workable web-applications break was working. Then I have recalled that "clean solution" and "rebuild" doesn't delete assemblies that left after renaming. And that was solution! I have manually cleaned `bin` directories of my buggy-web-applications and then saw new error in `Global.asax` `Inherits=""` attribute was referenced old dll. I have changed it on new and break began to work. Suppose that, during renaming Global.asax wasn't updated, and IIS took old assembly (with wrong routes) to start application.

Comment: Wow, that was a pain to find!  That's for the tip!

Comment: @Dao Really this is awesome, Thanks ;) I wasted couple of hours on this, I should have find your answer before :)

Comment: This was exactly my issue - thank you! I was going nuts. I was refactoring an ancient legacy application, and after renaming the web project, I couldn't get any code to fire. Worse, VS doesn't seem to let you edit the `Global.asax` file, so I had to edit it in Notepad.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem in a Project we had taken over after another vendor built it. The problem was that while there were a number of commands written by the previous vendor in Global.asax.cs, which might lead you to believe it was in use, it was actually being ignored entirely. Global.asax wasn't inheriting from it, and it's easy to never see this file if the .cs file is present - you have to right-click Global.asax and click View Markup to actually see it.

Global.asax:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
```

Needed to be changed to:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="ProjectNamespace.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

Where ProjectNamespace is whatever the namespace is of your Global.asax.cs class (usually the name of your Project).

In our case the file contained a bunch of inline code, some of which was copy-pasted from the .cs file, some not. We just dumped the inline code over to the .cs file and gradually merged our changes back in.

Comment: That was it. I added an exception to App start (as per Prisoner ZERO's answer) and it wasn't firing at all, so nothing to do with the debugger. Updating the Global.asax markup fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

Try switching the managed pipeline mode for the app pool to "Classic" instead of "Integrated". That solved the problem for me. Looking into the reason now...

(Props for this answer belong to Flores (see his comment on his own answer), I just wanted to provide this as a separate answer to draw more attention to it)

Comment: Yes, it works. But if you assume that your application should work under integrated app pool, than it should be debugged under integrated pool too.

Comment: My application also would not hit breakpoints after "F5" when I switched from Classic to Integrated.  Did you ever discover why?  I don't have any requirement to use Integrated, but it's discouraging when these things don't work for no explicable reason.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that your global.asax in not under a subdirectory. It has to be placed at root level into your project.

Comment: Thank you SO much!!! You saved me from going insane! This was exactly what was causing my problem.

Comment: My issue was that I just created a class called `Global.asax.cs` and expected it to work. You need to create it using `Add` -> `New Item` -> `Global Application Class` so that it is created with the corresponding `Global.asax` web forms config file.

Answer (score 4):

We had a similar problem, where global.asax.cs was being ignored.

It turns out that the site was upgraded from a precompiled .NET 2 web site to a .NET 4.0 site.  On the server, the `PrecompiledApp.config` file had not been deleted from the root folder.  After deleting it, and recycling the IIS app pool and touching web.config to restart the application, code in Global.asax.cs started working fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem once where the Global.asax and Global.asax.cs were not actually copied to IIS folder by the deployment scripts...
So it worked when debugging on the development server, but not under IIS.

Comment: I had the same problem. after I uploaded Global.asax to server, problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

A late entry...

To test whether or not the IIS Application gets started before the debugger has had enough time to attach just add this to the top or bottom of your GLOBAL.ASAX's `Application_Start`.

```
throw new ApplicationException("Yup, it fired");
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem when using a static page (e.g. index.html) as the start up page - Application-Start does not get called.   I discovered that serving a static page does not actually start the application.  Requesting an .aspx page does.

Comment: This is was what did it for me. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the namespaces in Global.asax and Global.asax.cs are same. If they are different it will not throw any error but will not hit the breakpoint also because it is not executing application_start at all.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "debug", do you mean actually launching the application from Visual Studio's built-in webserver for debugging, or do you mean attaching to the process in IIS? If it's the former, you should hit Application_Start, but if it's the latter, it can be difficult to be on the process early enough to catch it.

Comment: Correct, I do mean launching the app from VS. I have it hosted in IIS, so VS is attaching to that process. Are you saying that the event fires before before VS can attach to the process?

Answer (score 2):

Close Visual Studio and delete the `bin` and `obj` folders in your web project (or all projects in the solution).

Here are commands to delete these folders from all of your projects:

```
rm *\bin -r
rm *\obj -r
```

Answer (score 2):

I had made some changes based on "Code Analysis on Build" from Visual Studio. Code Analysis suggested "CA1822 Mark members as static" for Application_Start() in Global.asax. I did that and ended up with this problem.

I suggest suppressing this Code Analysis message, and not alter the signature of methods/classes automatically created by platform used for bootstrapping the Application. The signature of the method Application_Start probably was non-static for a reason.

I reverted to this method-signature and Application_Start() was firing again:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the application start event only gets fired when the first request is made, are you hitting your website (i.e. making a request)?

Comment: Yes I am making a request to the application.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in a .net 4 web forms vs2010 project and tried everything mentioned on this page. Ended up removing and adding global.asax actually resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same problem, couldn't catch Application_Start.
And the reason was that it was not firing do to a missmatch in the markup file.
**The markup file Global.asax was inheriting another class...**

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the Project settings?
I had this problem and I had the Start URL going to a different port than my server specific port.
It took me too long to figure out...

Answer (score 1):

After trying as many of the other answers as were applicable in my situation and having no luck with any of them, I went into the properties for the Web project (the server-side project for a Silverlight app using RIA Services), clicked on the "Web" tab and changed the selected Server from "Local IIS" to "IIS Express". (Note I'm using VS2013.) This solved the problem. Application_Start executes under "IIS Express" but not under "Local IIS". Interesting...

Comment: It is being executed. You're simply not being able to debug it since you either haven't attached to the IIS process, or attached to it after it's being executed.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to step through code in RegisterRoutes() called from Application start and not hitting my breakpoint.  I determined Application_Start was not getting called.  I had to make a change to make a superficial change to App_start/RouteConfig.cs and save it before Application_Start would get called. I guess these files get cached somewhere and are not called unless a change is made.

Answer (score 1):

**My same issue has been resolved by Adding reference of `System.Web.Routing` assembly in project**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); workaround (which I think is just fine for temporary use) and it's "just not working" on your Windows 8 Machine.  The reason is a bug in Visual Studio's "Just in time debugging".

**The fix is as follows is to fix the key for the "Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger"**

Open regedit and go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID{E62A7A31-6025-408E-87F6-81AEB0DC9347}
for the ‘AppIDFlags’ registry value, set the flag to 0x8

**More info here:**
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770786/just-in-time-debugging-operation-attempted-is-not-supported

Answer (score 0):

In my case, killing the built-in ASP.NET Development Server instance via the system tray resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Weird and crazy stuff... but debugging on a server machine and another user left IIS Express running on their session. I had to logoff that user to kill his running IIS Express processes. That seems to have fixed the problem!

**Update**

After spending more than 1 hour chasing what was causing the problem... here's the deal: I somewhat managed to type an **`s`** inside the `<appSettings>` section in `Web.config`. Visual Studio tried to warn me in the `Error List` window with a *warning*. I confess I rarely check warnings... should start checking it from now on. :D As soon as I removed the offending **`s`** the breakpoint got hit in `Application_Start`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when trying to initialize log4net.   I decided to just make a static constructor for the Global.asax

```
static Global(){
//Do your initialization here statically
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem mainly occurs when you try to relocate the Global.asax file to another solution directory. Relocate the Global.asax file again into the default location. It will work as expected.

Comment: What if everything in the website is precompiled, including Global.asax.aspx? I have precompiled files in the bin directory. Application_Start is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions described above worked for me.
However reinstalling the package

```
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

using nuget gui is a (not too nice) walkaround