# Why does not the Application_Start() event fire when I debug my ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, compilation

I currently have the following routines in my `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                                          
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                       
        new { controller = "Arrangement", action = "Index", id = "" }
    );
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    // Debugs the routes with Phil Haacks routing debugger (link below)
    RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

[Routing debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)...

When I hit `F5`, the application fires up and unless I have a view named `Index.aspx` in the `~/Views/Home/` folder, I get the "View missing" error message, although I have re-defined the default route and removed the `HomeController`. I would expect to get the routing debugger, and if not that at least a request for `~/Views/Arrangement/Index.aspx`.
A breakpoint on `RegisterRoutes(Routetable.Routes);` is never hit when debugging.

I have tried building, rebuilding, restarting VS, cleaning, rebuilding again etc, but nothing seems to work. Why doesn't the application run the current version of the code?

Comment: Thomas, it's a very interesting problem :) (+1)

Comment: Are you on development webserver? Check if the same problem present with your app working under IIS and then with new empty mvcapp?

Comment: Debugging on IIS instead of the development webserver did not help. A breakpoint on the same line in a brand new MVC Application was indeed hit, so we can narrow it down to something project-specific. What could it be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem:

This MVC application was part of a larger solution, in which I had at one point set another project to build for an x86 environment (I'm running x64). When I did that, apparently all other projects - even those added later - were set not to build on `Ctrl+Shift+B`, and I suppose that's why the debugger didn't hit my breakpoint.

Solution:

Go into the solution build properties (right-click Solution, select properties, and select Build on the menu on the left), and put a check in the Build checkbox next to the project name in the list.

Answer (score 114):

I found the following answer [on forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1233037.aspx/1):

> Are you using IIS7 as the server or the built-in web server?  I noticed when using IIS7 that if you start the debugger, let a page come up, then change Global.asax (the markup file, not code-behind) while the debugger is still running, then refresh the page, breakpoints in Application_Start will be hit.
>
> I think what's happening is that pressing "play", VS just fires up the process, then attaches to it, but by the time it attaches to it the start event has already run.  By changing Global.asax, you cause the app to restart and since the debugger's already attached you can hit the breakpoint. Not a great solution, but it seems to work.

Thats's what was happening in my case.

Comment: +1 as useful tip for IIS7 users. Maybe you have sub domain routing or some other reason you can't use the built in web server or if there are any problems with the above suggestion - e.g. with editing of part of the class you are wanting to debug, the other way to force a restart of the app easily in VS is to edit web.config see my comment here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641148/application-start-not-firing/7655582#7655582)

Comment: what does it mean "the markup file, not code-behind" ?

Comment: Man it works!
Thanks a ton, but what's the reason behind this?

Comment: @user3311522, on the file system you'll find in the project folder a file Global.asax and a file Global.asax.cs. The first one is the 'markup file'. It contains something like `<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyApplication" Language="C#" %> `. It can be opened from the _Solution Explorer_ by context menu option _View Markup_ on the Global.asax item. Adding a trailing space and saving the file will suffice to restart the application.

Comment: WTF. Thanks fot the solution. It works! But... there be a cleaner way to handle this... With VS 2015 over IIS 8 this problem still occurs...

Answer (score 35):

Add a `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` to `Application_Start()`.

 This will force a breakpoint.

This line should be commented out to avoid the breakpoint to happen and `#ifdef debug` to get  sure never gets to production.

NOTE: this is a problem with IIS. Since I wrote this answer, things have changed, and you can avoid doing this by using other servers, like IIS Express.

Comment: Sounds like really bad practice - why would you want to clutter your code with instructions to the IDE?

Comment: Not a very bad practice at all. It's a simple instruction to make debugging easier. Using `#ifdef debug` allows you to avoid it from being compiled on production version. And you can use it temporarily while you need to debug and finally delete it. Please, let me know whihc are the best practices of `Debugger.Launch()` and `Debugger.Break()`. This utility methods are extremely helpful to help debug har-to-debug things like VS add-ins, Windows Services and so on, without having to manually attach the process on every run. Some people prefer to be purist. I prefer being practical.

Comment: I tried doing this in Global.asax and was unable to get it to work.  YMMV.

Comment: Good idea but it does not work with Application_Start().

Comment: @Telemat I've used it in Application_Start(). Are you compiling the Debug version or the Release version of your code? I don't know why it can be fialing for you. What kind of project is it? Which version?

Comment: @JotaBe - "Some people prefer to be purist. I prefer being practical"  Awesome comment, agree 100%!  Also, your solution worked great as well, many thanks.

Answer (score 21):

The problem is `Application_Start()` triggers first then the debugger attaches.

So the goal is to do something that would cause `Application_Start()` to trigger again while its still running. For debugging purposes, just run the debugger like you normally do then edit (eg add a newline) and save the web.config file.

Answer (score 18):

I believe you have to shutdown/stop the local debugging server in order for the `Application_Start()` event to fire again... you should be able to right click on it in the system tray and choose "Stop".

Comment: I did. And even today - after shutting down the computer overnight - the problem persists...

Answer (score 8):

I hit with the same problem today and was using Local IIS.

I believe this arises because because of the way page is loaded. 
All you need to do is, put a breakpoint in Application_Start. Run the application(In my case, it took to Login Screen ) and then go to web.config. Edit it - by adding some spaces. and then refresh in Browser.that will hit the breakpoint on Application_Start.

Comment: This is the best answer to this forum post. As soon as I saved web config, the `application_start` event was hit by the debugger.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was between chair and keyboard - after renaming mvc project assembly, I forgot to update Global.asax to point to the correct class. So check the "Inherits" in Global.asax (in visual studio right-click on Global.asax -> View Markup)

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" 
  Inherits="Monster.MgsMvc.Web.MvcApplication" 
  Language="C#" %>
```

if it really matches your Global.asax.cs class/namespace declaration

Answer (score 4):

In my case was I using

**Local IIS Web server** in web project settings

and I change to **Use Visual Studio Development Server**, and this works.

Answer (score 4):

Below technique worked for me: 
Simple workaround is to touch global.asax after the debugger is attached in order to force an application recycle. Then during the next request, the break point that you set on Application_Start will be hit.

I found this here:
 http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/634919/cannot-debug-application-start-event-in-global-asax

Comment: One more solution is put Debugger.Break();

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my solution will help someone:

1. Stop the debugger.
2. Update the `RegisterRoutes` code (example - add\remove `int i = 1;`).
3. Rebuild.
4. Place a break point in `RegisterRoutes`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this problem and swapped from Local IIS to IIS Express in project properties -> web to sort it out

Answer (score 0):

project -> property -> web

check "Native code".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

None of all worked except this

Project -> Righ click -> Properties -> Web -> Change port number in Project Url and press Create Virtual Directory button

Now debug