# How to speed up my Nhibernate configuration

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ASP.NET MVC4 web api that uses fluent NHibernate, but when I run debug it takes 1½ min to access any site that uses the database the first time I try, so I found [Fluent nHibernate Slow Startup Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382870/fluent-nhibernate-slow-startup-time) but I am not sure how to utilize that,

When it runs on the live server it must garbage collect the session data as it takes ages to configure again if I havent used it for a long time.

Is it possiible to cut it down to maybe sub 10 seconds instead of 1.5 minutes?

My current SessionFactory class looks like this

```
public class SessionFactory
{
    private static readonly string ConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    private static ISessionFactory _session;
    private static readonly object SyncRoot = new Object();

    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MySQLConfiguration
            .Standard
            .ConnectionString(ConnString))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMap>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(UpdateSchema)
                .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    private static void UpdateSchema(Configuration cfg)
    {
        new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true);
    }

    public static ISession Session
    {
        get
        {
            if (_session == null)
            {
                lock (SyncRoot)
                {
                    if (_session == null)
                        _session = CreateSessionFactory();
                }
            }
            return _session.OpenSession();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of a dotTrace[image]

Timing the request on my host it takes 1 min and 50 seconds for the initial request, and thats on "live" server (I cant control the IIS there)

Comment: Have you tried it without UpdateSchema? Don't think you need to do that more than just once per model change.

Comment: How should it then look, I thought I usd schemaupdate for normal requests and then schema export when I needed to create anything?

Comment: You can just comment out .ExposeConfiguration(UpdateSchema) and see if that is any faster for now... on a QA server preferably. =)

Comment: I think that did it, now its down to less than 10sec in debug mode, could you make a reply I can mark as answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a host of things wrong with this code.  Your CreateSessionFactory should only ever be called once in the lifetime of your application.  Create a static variable in global.asax and call CreateSessionFactory once in Application_Start().  Also in global.asax, you want to setup some events for Application_BeginRequest and Application_EndRequest.  This is where you are going to create and destory sessions.  This is your unit of work in a web application.  You should also store your session in the HttpContext.

```
public static ISession CurrentSession
{
    get { return (ISession)HttpContext.Current.Items[sessionkey]; }
    set { HttpContext.Current.Items[sessionkey] = value; }
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    CurrentSession = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
}

protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    if (CurrentSession != null)
        CurrentSession.Dispose();
}
```

Your code recreates the SessionFactory every time you need a session.

Comment: Just a quick note: If you look again at his code, you'll see Mech0z is using a [Singleton pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternSingleton.aspx) for the factory (misleadingly called "_session"). The factory gets created only the first time a session is requested.

Comment: oh.  i see that now.  my bad.

Comment: @Fran great info! This really helped me understand how to design with FNH within ASP.NET web api. I also ran into a situation where when debugging Application_Start, the debugger would not attach, see this thread if anyone else is having seeing that issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967813/why-does-not-the-application-start-event-fire-when-i-debug-my-asp-net-mvc-app/4339543#4339543