# VS Express 2013 for Web: How to use the internal VS server, not IIS express?

Tags: iis, web, internal, visual-studio-2013

I switched to Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web, but I've just stumbeled into something. It's default settings are set so that it uses IIS Express as a default web server, and there isn't a button that could change that, as in VS Express 2012 for Web before. I was looking for that option in the settings and in the properties / property page for my project, but I can't find it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response :) You can add it as an answer, so that I could chose it as a best one and if there's anyone with the same problem, he could see it :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's been discontinued. The options are IIS Express or IIS. And that's for the full range of the product, not just a VS Express thing.

I can't find a specific posting about it, but in e.g. [Accessing the ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool in Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx), it starts with:

> As many of you have noticed, the option to select “ASP.Net Web Configuration Manager” is no longer in Visual Studio 2013 Preview. **This is due to the removal of the Visual Studio Development Server (or Cassini)** from the product. However, ...

(**My emphasis**)