# How to execute Page or Code after website is published on IIS or IIS starts

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have an ASP .NET WebSite project (Web Forms) hosted on IIS 7 
but I need to execute the application_start (Global.asax) because I load some stuffs there., so I'm looking for a way to execute this code right after I publish the code and/or when IIS restart,

I don't need to debug, I just need to run a process in the application_start to load the cache info in a background process.,

So the first time I open the website be able to run it fast and all cache data will be available, and the application_start runs the first time the website is executed/opened so that's why I need to find an automatic way to execute the application_start right after the IIS is restarted or the website is published.,  right now I need to manually open the website

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application\_start not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973106/application-start-not-working)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/590865/how-can-i-warm-up-my-asp-net-mvc-webapp-after-an-app-pool-recycle, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658849/iis-app-pool-restart-and-asp-net, please read [ask] and share your research.

Comment: cool, let me try that..

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [Application Initialization module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization) in IIS.The original article is quite overwhelming ,a

- install the Application Initialization Module
- After the feature has been installed and you have configured an ASP.NET web site, set the startMode of the application pool  to AlwaysRunning.

([image: set the startMode in IIS]

> Setting the startMode will start the Application and thus >will trigger your Application_Start in global.asax.